# How to convert a Map<K, V> into two list while keeping the order?

Tags: java

How can I convert a `Map<K, V>` into lists`List<K> keys`, `List<V> values`, such that the order in `keys` and `values` match? I can only find `Set<K> Map#keySet()` and `Collection<V> Map#values()` which I could convert to lists using:

```
List<String> keys   = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(map.values());
```

but I worry that the order will be random.

Is it correct that I have to manually convert them or is there a shortcut somewhere?

Update: Owing to the answers I was able to find additional, useful information which I like to share with you, random google user: 
[How to efficiently iterate over each Entry in a Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-do-i-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map)

Comment: I think ArrayList preserves order in which we insert.

Comment: @AchintyaJha yes, it does. However, is the set that is returned by the map ordered?

Comment: +1 for not assuming that the two collections (keys and values) will have the same ordering.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use Map.entrySet():

```
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(map.size());
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>(map.size());
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry: map.entrySet()) {
   keys.add(entry.getKey());
   values.add(entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: +1, but let's upgrade to Java 1.5 and use generics. After all, Java 1.8 is just around the corner.

Comment: Totally agree -- I just wasn't using an IDE and getting them right can be tricky without one.

Comment: Edited to reflect java 7 generics.

Answer (score 1):

You should extract the list of keys as you mentioned and then iterate over them and extract the values:

```
List<String keys = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String key: keys) {
    values.add(map.get(key));
}
```

Comment: You could also iterate over the `entrySet`, to get both keys and values.

Comment: That's true - complexity wise it's the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over [`map.entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29), appending the keys and values to the two lists.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that Map is not an ordered Collection. The iteration order is not fixed. So as you add more entries into your Map they will appear at random points in the iteration and thus will no longer match any lists you created.

If you need the iteration order of a Map to be the same as the insertion order than have a look at [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

Comment: I do not care about the order, except that I need a pair (key, value) at the same "position" in the two resulting lists.

Comment: Doesn't this do the `iterator`? True, you can't be sure in which order the map is, but you can make sure that when iterating through the `entrySet` the `Iterator` iterates in a specific order.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann: well then you have nothing to worry about when putting the values in your two lists. Just take special care when altering the lists afterwards.